# Battery draining faster after recharging on Galaxy S4 Mini

Tags: charging, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I'm struggling with my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini. Actually the battery is very good and since I don't use my phone a lot, it lasts pretty much 2 days when I let it die and full recharge it.

The issue is, everytime I recharge it when the battery is not dead, the battery is draining very fast even though I don't use my phone.

[image: battery info]

As you can see, after I unplugged it, even though everything was off, the curve is plunging whereas when everything was off before the plug, it's almost horizontal.

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Well, let us try running a check over this one: Try removing the battery from the device and then put it over the flat surface, and try spinning if the battery spins freely then battery may be swollen and needs replacement.

Comment: I've just tried, so far the battery looks flat and makes only one turn after spinning it. Since the battery lasts long the first time, i would bet on a software problem, no ?

Comment: Okay, @sebcarotte that looks like the problem isn't with the battery as only one spinning can be considered as non spinning at all ! I would say why don't you try recalibrating battery.

Comment: Thanks Peter, By recalibrating, you mean, full recharge the battery and let it go to 0% once or twice in a row?

Comment: Yes @Sebcarotte I am talking about the same full charge the battery let it ran to 0% and then again full charge the battery and let it ran dry. Sometimes it also helps !

Comment: All the best ! I'll be looking forward to hear back from you! :D

Comment: Draining a lithium-ion battery to 0 should only be done on occasion. It is not good for li-ion batteries to be drained fully.